Android JUnit includeAndroidResources launches main application
I am trying to write tests using RobolectricTestRunner. In these tests i want to access Android Resources, so i add the following line to app module's build.gradle file -
android {
...
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

But now when i run the test, i see that it launches the MainApplication class. Which causes other issues. I would like to understand why this happens and if there is a way to fix this? Or maybe another way to access resources in Robolectric tests?
